# 2 div on the same line, but the second div will wrap when a short width is added, why?

Tags: css

The following are 2 div, side by side.  But once a `width: 100px` is added to `#right`, they won't be side by side any more.  The second div will wrap to the next line.  The browser's width is like 1200px, so it is not a concern, and this happens on both Firefox and Chrome.  What is a reason for that?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<style>
  #left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
  }

  #right {

  }
</style>

<div id='left'>
  hello
</div>

<div id='right'>
  world
</div>
```

Comment: Do I have this right? http://jsfiddle.net/orolo/S5qnJ/

Comment: yes, and when a width is added to `#right`, they are not side by side any more...

Answer (score 1):

Floats are funny things in CSS. They can easily cause this kind of confusion.

I recommend using `display:inline-block;` (on both the divs) instead of `float:left;` in your example. It'll probably behave closer to how you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left to the #right, it will fix the problem. Divs are positioned on new lines if the float is not specified.

Comment: note that the question is, why will it happen?  I usually float the second div too, but just wonder why the width make such difference

Comment: I think adding dimensions to the div changes it's float. By the way, in IE7 even when you add dimensions they are in the same line. So I would guess it's the browser behavior. By default the elements have no float.

Comment: supposedly, when the left div is floated, it is "taken out of the normal document float"... and it is positioned at the left, and then the second div should now consider the canvas in that shape and start the normal float of the document.  So the "side by side" behavior is standard.  Why when there is a width, it changes, might be something subtle about the spec.